# React Hooks and POST method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, fetch

I need to understand how can I setup a custom hook in React, for a POST method.

If I need to POST some data after a click, but I can't use the custom hook in an event handler, how can I do It?

I made a custom Hook with all the fetch logic and the relative reducers, but I don't know, how to use It in a click, without breaking the rules.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All you need is a handler that triggers post method

```
const useFetchData = ({url, headers, payload}) => {
    const [res, setRes] = useState({data: null, error: null, isLoading: false});
    const [error, setError]
    // You POST method here
    const callAPI = useCallback(() => {
         setRes(prevState => ({...prevState, isLoading: true}));
         axios.post(url, headers, payload).then(res => {
            setRes({data: res.data, isLoading: false, error: null});
         }).catch((error) => {
            setRes({data: null, isLoading: false, error});
         })
    }, [url, headers, payload])
    return [res, callAPI];
}
```

Now you can use this hook in your code and on any event handler just call `callAPI` returned from the hook like

```
const MyFunc = () => {
   const [res, apiMethod] = useFetchData({url: 'some url here', headers: {ContentType: 'text/plain'}, payload: {}});

   return (
      <button onClick={() => {apiMethod()}} type="button">Submit data</button>
   )
}
```

You could event have payload defined in the component state and pass it on to the `useFetchData` as argument.

Comment: this solution won't work if you try to use apiMethod inside an useEffect. an infinite loop will happen

Comment: but in my case res i am getting {data:null,error:null,isLoading:false} even network shows correct value for response

Comment: for those using typescript the return type needs to be return [res, callAPI] as const;

Comment: Yep - I got an infinite loop with `useEffect` and the API i was using rate limited me

Comment: @cacoder because your dependency array of `useCallback` for payload or headers may be an Object or Array and in javascript compare two similar object always return false for example `{} !== {} ` because they're compared with it's reference,  for solving your problem you must change you dependency array to `[url, JSON.stringify(headers), JSON.stringify(payload)] `